# Latex need citation "et al." in Roman

Tags: fonts, citing

I'm submitting a paper to a journal. In a citation when there a multiple authors it appears "First author, et al. [1]" but the "et al." appears italic. The journal want it to be Roman. I did some search but can't find any working solution. Below is my MWE. Appreciate any help!

```
\documentclass[times,sort&compress,3p]{elsarticle}
\journal{Journal of XXX}

%Temporary Bibliography
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{yuan2007,
    Title                    = {Dimension reduction and coefficient estimation in multivariate linear regression},
    Author                   = {Yuan, Ming and Ekici, Ali and Lu, Zhaosong and Monteiro, Renato},
    Journal                  = {Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B},
    Year                     = {2007},
    Number                   = {3},
    Pages                    = {329-346},
    Volume                   = {69},
}
\end{filecontents}
\immediate\write18{bibtex \jobname}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
    \title{This is a title}         
    \author[uc]{Jane Doe}
    \address[uc]{Address of UC}     
    \date{\today}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Intro}
This is bla bla, \citet{yuan2007}
\bibliography{\jobname}{}
\bibliographystyle{rss}
%\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe it has somethign to do with natbib. In elsarticle documentation https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/56843/elsdoc-1.pdf it mentioned using \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}, but didn't work. It also mentioned \biboptions{}  but I don't know how to set this up...

Comment: When using `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}`, I obtain [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYlEx.png), with `et al.` in roman. Perhaps you should add `\listfiles` to your preamble and post your `.log`.

Comment: Where did you find `rss.bst`?

Comment: @Werner you are right. This MWE can't explain my situation. I have more complicated situations and change to \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names} didn't give me Roman font. Let me figure out another MWE... Thanks.